# nasm x86-64 assembly - two variables read as one variable

Tags: assembly, nasm

I am making a simple program to print "Hello, world!" in hex ASCII characters.
Here is my code:

```
SECTION .DATA
msg db 'Printing Hello world in ASCII values: ', 0
msglen EQU $-msg
char1 db 064h  ; 'd' character
char2 db 06Ch  ; 'l' character
char3 db 072h  ; 'r' 
char4 db 06Fh  ; 'o'
char5 db 077h  ; 'w'
char6 db 020h  ; (space)
char7 db 06Fh  ; 'o'
char8 db 06Ch  ; 'l'      
char9 db 06Ch  ; 'l'
char10 db 065h ; 'e'
char11 db 048h ; 'H'

SECTION .bss

SECTION .text

GLOBAL _start:
_start:
nop
mov esi, 0

mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1
mov ecx, msg
mov edx, msglen
int 80h
; printing 'H'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char11 
mov edx, 1
int 80h

; printing 'e'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char10
mov edx, 1
int 80h

; printing 'l'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char9
mov edx, 1
int 80h     

; printing 'l'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char8 
mov edx, 1
int 80h 

; printing 'o'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char7 
mov edx, 1
int 80h 

; printing space
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char6 
mov edx, 1
int 80h 

; printing 'w'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char5 
mov edx, 1
int 80h

; printing 'o'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char4 
mov edx, 1
int 80h

; printing 'r'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char3 
mov edx, 1
int 80h

; printing 'l'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char2 
mov edx, 1
int 80h

; printing 'd'
mov eax, 4
mov ebx, 1  
mov ecx, char1 
mov edx, 1
int 80h

    ; end
mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 80h
```

MY QUESTION:

How can I do something like this:

```
loop:
    mov eax, 4
    mov ebx, 1
    mov ecx, char[incremented variable]
    mov edx, 1
    int 80h
    inc (incremented variable)
    jmp loop
```

What I mean is how can I have a variable and an incrementing counter be read as one variable?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'd need to make an array out for your string, the same way `msg` is declared, the load the pointer to that string, dereference to get that character, check if its 0, break if so, else print and increment the pointer.

eg: (MASM syntax, sorry)

```
msg2 BYTE "Hello World!",0

MOV ESI, OFFSET msg2

LOOP1:

MOVZX ECX, BYTE PTR[ESI]
TEST ECX,ECX
JE NEXT
MOV EAX, 4
MOV EBX, 1
MOV EDX, 1
INT 80h
INC ESI
JMP LOOP1

NEXT:
...
```

Just noticed that your title states x86-64, but your code (and my code), is plain x86, if you are actually wanting x64 code, the ABI for the syscall's changes a bit, but the rest is pretty much the same.

Comment: @AussieGamer: just added one, unfortunately, I don't use nasm, so I had to use masm syntax, they are roughly the same however.

Comment: Yes, I am on a 64-bit Linux machine, hopefully that's fine. I used to do MASM assembly, but I changed to Linux. I also never got around to using arrays, hence this post.

Answer (score 0):

Putting the character into ecx isn't going to work! (segfault) ecx wants to be the address (offset).

```
mov ecx, mystring ; address! (Masm uses "offset")
looptop:
cmp byte [ecx], 0 ; "[contents]"
jz done
mov edx, 1 ; length
mov ebx, 1 ; stdout
mov eax, 4 ; __NR_write
int 80h
inc ecx ; next address
jmp  looptop
done:
...
```

... something like that... If you really want 64-bit code, the system call numbers are different - 1 for write and... 3Ch(?) for exit. Use `syscall` instead of 'int 80h` (and 64-bit regs, of course). If you want to do 32-bit code with a 64-bit ld, tell ld "-m elf_i386".

Comment: If you want Masm-like syntax for Linux, look for Jwasm ("japheth.de" I think) or (G)as with ".intel-syntax noprefix" is pretty close.

Answer (score 0):

Wait a minute. Did you want to print hex values (in text) of the characters instead of the characters? Something like this? (highly unoptimized)

```
global _start

section .data
    msg db "Hello World", 0
    hexbuf db "0xXX, "
    hexbuflen equ $ - hexbuf

section .text
_start:
mov esi, msg
looptop:
    mov al, [esi]
    test al, al
    jz done
    inc esi
    mov ah, al
    and al, 0Fh
    cmp al, 9
    jna skip
    add al, 7
skip:
    add al, '0'
    mov [hexbuf + 3], al
    mov al, ah
    shr al, 4
    and al, 0Fh
    cmp al, 9
    jna skip2
    add al, 7
skip2:
    add al, '0'
    mov [hexbuf + 2], al
    mov edx, hexbuflen
    mov ecx, hexbuf
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h
    jmp looptop
done:
    push 10
    mov ecx, esp
    mov edx, 1
    mov ebx, 1
    mov eax, 4
    int 80h
    add esp, 4

    mov eax, 1
    xor ebx, ebx
    int 80h
;-----------------
```